# Double square brackets in Vue.js data

Tags: vue.js

I am doing some charting tutorials that leverage Vue.js. Excellent charts and I am a big fan of Vue.js, but recently came across double square brackets. I have no idea how to generate this with JSON data? For instance I can build an array that looks like this:

```
[{book:"2"},{phone:"3"},{television:"10"}]
```

How would I generate an array that looks like this one:

```
[["book",2],["Phone",2],["television",22]]
```

with double brackets from an AJAX response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume each element in the original array has exactly one key / value pair:

```js
arr = [{book:"2"},{phone:"3"},{television:"10"}]

newarr = arr.map(obj => Object.entries(obj)[0])
console.log(newarr)
// [ [ 'book', '2' ], [ 'phone', '3' ], [ 'television', '10' ] ]
```

Comment: would this go in a method if I have a data-model that will leverage this on an array? where would I trigger this at?